# Improve video quality by lowering framerate

Tags: video, video-quality, video-recording, framerate, windows

I have recorded a short movie using GoPro camera 1080p / Wide / 60fps. The video is really blurry, despite the fact that it was a quite good weather outside (middle of the day, partially cloudly). Is it possible to make the video sharper by lowering the framerate? All I need is 25% of speed, so 15fps. I'm just wondering if some video editing software can use the information from skipped frames to improve the video quality.

Here is the sample frame: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uCBy.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your individual frames are blurry, cutting down the frame rate won't help. I assume that you mean you'll be converting the 60 fps footage to 15 fps in real time (cutting out 3/4 of the frames rather than keeping all the frames but slowing it down to appear 15 fps).

Think of it this way: changing the frame rate doesn't change the **actual frames**. If you slowly scroll through your footage frame-by-frame and it's blurry, then it will be blurry at any speed or frame rate.

Comment: I understand this clearly, but I believe that there is a possibility to blend unused frames with actual frames to make them less blurry.

Comment: Temporal noise reduction is a technique whereby image data from adjacent frames can be used to reduce sensor noise.  It tends to work best when the camera and the subject are both static.  But as @John Barton says, this does nothing for blurriness.  There is a technique called "convolutional deblurring", but it requires very hands-on intervention to get a decent result.  If you are trying to solve a crime and you have 15 blurry frames, you might hire an expert to pull whatever detail they can to create the one magic frame that will help you identify a suspect, but not practical for video.

Comment: Yeah, if every frame is blurry, you're out of luck. Best-case scenario, if exactly every 4th frame isn't blurry, dropping down to 15 fps would solve your problem perfectly. However, if you have any frames at all that aren't blurry, chances are, they're not going to be perfectly placed every 4th frame. Manually going through and picking out the "perfect" frames would remove all blur but the timing wouldn't look right at all.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically it IS possible, and there are working, practical, proof-of-concept research on the subject.
A couple of examples:

- [Learning to Extract Flawless Slow Motion from Blurry Videos](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPR_2019/papers/Jin_Learning_to_Extract_Flawless_Slow_Motion_From_Blurry_Videos_CVPR_2019_paper.pdf)
- [Blurry Video Frame Interpolation](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.12259)

The picture below is from the second paper.
[image: Figure 1 from paper "Blurry Video Frame Interpolation", showing the extraction of higher quality images from blurry original video]

However, as of this writing, I couldn't find any feasible-to-use, (commercial or otherwise) software to achieve that.
You could actually use the techniques above to apply it to your video, since they even offer the code on Github, but it would be a great effort, you'd need to basically build a video processing pipeline script/software for that.
It probably would also be somewhat computationally intensive (slow).

Comment: This issue on the VidStab project GitHub also tackles the same issue:  https://github.com/georgmartius/vid.stab/issues/24